# How to implement Google App indexing for Android

Tags: android, google-api, deep-linking, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

How should I properly implement google app indexing for android. I mean should I care about local autocompletion and web search separately?
Here are two URLs:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/app-indexing/#0

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish#add-app-indexing-api-calls

Which one should I use? What is essetial differnce between these two guides?
Is the first one for autocompletion only, and the second one for just ranking web pages?

Answer (score 3):

Those two documents are the same. Codelab will get you started on how to use app indexing API and how does it work. And https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish is the guide for adding app indexing api to your app.

Cheers,

MB

Comment: But in first case there is  a deep link with some structure and in the second case you just pass a web url

Comment: The developer docs are more up to date than the codelab but both methods work. The parameter on the dev docs is not the web URL it is the deep link but it assumes the deep link also uses HTTP scheme