# How Index Android App in Google Search

Tags: android, google-play, google-index

Following the Google guide I didn't understand this:

I want link my Store page in the Google Index like here below:

[image: index]

I read about [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android#set-up-firebase-and-the-dynamic-links-sdk) but I really don't need all this features like deep link..., I just need to index my Store App Page.

How can I do that? **Am I force to have a website** and integrate the Firebase Library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Google App indexing for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137121/how-to-implement-google-app-indexing-for-android)

Comment: Did you go through the Doc which specifies the criteria for Indexing App?

Comment: 1. You app name will be used for indexing your app into play store and other google services. 2. Add deeplinks to enable quicker accessibility of your app from other services. I remember these two major points, You can read whole doc for further clarity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really a programming question. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic